# Trying to share an iOS .app file but it crashes as soon as it starts. Also I see a blocked symbol on my .app file

Tags: ios, xcode, ipa, diawi

[image]

I am compressing this file to .zip and uploading it to https://www.diawi.com/ and sharing the link which is generated.

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 0):

I'm quite sure you need to archive it first (Top menu go to Product > Archive) and then export (Distribute -> Ad Hoc) the zip from that archive. Use the zip you get and upload that to diawi.